# How to select item/s in list based on value and also next and last neighbor in python

Tags: python

I have a long list containing some text. Apart from that, there is a special value, it can be at any index, it can also be on multiple indexes followed by each other, but value is always same. What i need is to find that value and value before and value after.

Example list values:

- text
- text2
- text3
- special
- text4
- text5

I need: `text3 speacial, text4` That's easy, but how to do something like this:

- text
- text2
- text3
- special
- special
- special
- special
- text4
- text5

and the result should be now: `text3 speacial, speacial, speacial, speacial, text4`

The output of results is probably the best to be in dictionary, or whatever else usable:

`out1 : [text3 speacial, text4]`

`out2 : [text3 speacial, speacial, speacial, speacial, text4]`

Comment: You forgot to include what you have written to try and solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **index** method to get the index of the first element matching your item. Then, you loop inside the list until finding another element (the next one). Here is an example code:

```
def select_items(my_list, word):
    index = my_list.index(word)
    output = []
    if index > 0:
        output.append(my_list[index - 1])

    while index < len(my_list) and my_list[index] == word:
        output.append(my_list[index])
        index += 1

    if index < len(my_list):
        output.append(my_list[index])

    return output
```

If you are sure that your item is can only be found as consecutive items, you can also use the **count** method

```
def select_items(my_list, word):
    index = my_list.index(word)
    output = []
    if index > 0:
        output.append(my_list[index - 1])

    count = my_list.count(word)
    output.extend(my_list[index: index + count])

    if index + count < len(my_list):
        output.append(my_list[index + count])
    
    return output
```